# Rescale Graphics3D Based on Box Ratios

Tags: graphics3d

If I plot a sphere using `Graphics3D` with `BoxRatios->1`, then I get a nice looking plot:

```
Show[Graphics3D[{Red, Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1]}], BoxRatios -> 1, 
 PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {-4, 4}, {-4, 4}}]
```

Image:

[image: well-scaled sphere]

However, if `PlotRange` or `BoxRatios` changes, then the sphere gets distorted:

[image: distorted examples]

If I know the `BoxRatios` and `PlotRange` before plotting, I can use `Ellipsoid` to make something that appears spherical in any 3D plot:

[image: ellipsoid that appears spherical]

Question: Is there some way I can create my own custom "Graphics Object" that plots an ellipsoid in 3D that is scaled based on the dimensions of the plot (`BoxRatios` and `PlotRange`) to appear perfectly spherical? I would like my "Graphics Object" to automatically adjust to `BoxRatios` and `PlotRange` the same way that `PointSize` automatically adjusts to the width of the plot without need for user input.

Note: You might be curious why I am asking this question. The reason is that `Graphics3D[{PointSize[0.035],Red,Point[{0,0,0}]}]` produces a point in 3D that looks like a flat disk, and I would like to represent points in 3D as perfectly-scaled spheres. `Sphere` on its own is not a perfect answer because it can appear distorted based on the dimensions of the plot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** While we wait for some future release updates to `Sphere` that allows `Offset[o]` and `Scaled[s]` to specify the radius (as is currently the case for `Disk` and `Circle`) , we can use post-processing as follows:

If the input is a `Graphics` object and the option values `BoxRatios` and `PlotRange` are not known in advance, we can extract them from the object before we use `scaleSphere`.

```
Multicolumn[
 glist = Show[Graphics3D[{Red, Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1]}], BoxRatios -> #,
      PlotRange -> #2, 
     PlotLabel -> Row[{"BoxRatios: ", #, "\n  PlotRange: ", #2}], 
     ImageSize -> Medium] & @@@ ratiorangepairs, 2]
```

[image]

```
ClearAll[postProcess]
postProcess = # /. s_Sphere :> 
     scaleSphere[BoxRatios /. Quiet@AbsoluteOptions[#, BoxRatios], 
       PlotRange@#][s] &;


Multicolumn[#, 2] &[postProcess /@ glist]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

With known box ratios and plot ranges you can use [`Scale`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Scale.html) to construct a function to process `Sphere[...]`:

```
ClearAll[scaleSphere]

scaleSphere[br_, pr_] := Scale[#, Normalize[-Subtract @@@ pr, Max] / br] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
ratiorangepairs =  Tuples[{{1, {1, 2, 3}}, 
  {{{-4, 4}, {-4, 4}, {-4, 4}}, {{-4, 4}, {-4, 4}, {-1, 1}}}}]; 

Multicolumn[#, 2] &[Show[Graphics3D[{Red, scaleSphere[##]@Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1]}], 
    BoxRatios -> #, PlotRange -> #2, 
    PlotLabel -> Row[{"BoxRatios: ", #, "\n  PlotRange: ", #2}], 
    ImageSize -> Medium] & @@@ ratiorangepairs]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing this! I apologize if I was unclear--I want to spherically-scaled ellipsoids without knowing `BoxRatios` or `PlotRange` ahead of time. This would be similar to `Graphics3D[{PointSize[0.02],Point[{0,0,0}]}]` knowing to scale the point to 2% of the width of the plot without knowing the dimensions of the plot ahead of time.